# Can't comment strings with '*)' inside it

Tags: syntax

I believe it's a bug in notebook's comment parser. I can't comment strings with `*)` inside it. Something like:

```
(*"this is a bug*)"*)
```

I discovered it trying to comment a code with a regular expression `RegularExpression["((re)*)"]` inside it.

Can someone else check it?

Using V10.0.2 in MacOS

Comment: Same issue with V10.0.2.0 in Windows 8.1 (64 bit).

Comment: A quick fix: `RegularExpression["((re)*"<>")"]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We already have some answers explaining the issue. Let me give a solution to your problem. Let's say you have the code

```
RegularExpression["((re)*)"]
```

that you want to comment out. Since we have nested comments in *Mathematica*, just use a pair of `(*` to prevent your issue:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Although I don't know the internal implementation of *Mathematicas* parser, the reason why this goes wrong is pretty universal. Parsing is usually a two-step process. First, the input is broken down into tokens by a so-called [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and comments are often separated from the rest of the code in this stage. Taking your example

```
(* RegularExpression["((re)*)"] *)
```

this means the lexer first reads the token `COMMENT_OPEN`. Then, the lexer usually reads over everything until it meets the closing `*)`. And here it is important to know that the lexer really *stupidly* reads over the input.

Unfortunately, the next closing `*)` is inside the stuff you wanted to comment out. At this point the lexer leaves its *stupid comment mode* again and tries to tokenize real code. Now, he is in the middle of your expression and everything goes wrong.

Btw, using the [`fultzTokenize` of this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13095/187) shows how *Mathematica* breaks your code down. Note that I had to quote the quotes accordingly. See that strings are kept together when the lexer is in *code mode* when going over `str2`:

```
str1="(* RegularExpression[\"((re)*)\"] *)";
str2="RegularExpression[\"((re)*)\"]";
fultzTokenize/@{str1,str2}
```

```
  {(*, ,RegularExpression,[,"((re),*),"] *)}
  {     RegularExpression,[,"((re)*)",]}
```

Comment: +1 Clever.  It exploits the fact that _Mathematica_ is unusual among languages in that it supports nested matchfix comments (unlike, say, C).

Answer (score 9):

This behaviour is very common, possibly near universal, in programming languages with matchfix comment syntax.  The reason is that the contents of a comment sequence is presumed *not* to be code.  Usually that presumption is correct, but not in this case. The general rule is

> You should be able to put anything inside a comment and the only special tokens inside comments are the tokens `(*` and `*)` itself.

C, C++, Java and SQL, just to name a few, exhibit the same problem.  Those languages also offer a prefix syntax that can be used to work around the problem -- provided you can isolate the relevant expression to its own line.  C also offers a way to disable whole blocks of code using IFDEF, etc.

Unfortunately, *Mathematica* only offers the matchfix syntax.  Thus, there is no analog to the prefix/block notations in other languages.  A prefix comment syntax would probably make a good addition to the language -- but there are mighty few left-over special characters for that purpose :). Additionally, we should not forget that *lines* don't really exist in the front-end since it shuffles code around automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I would not call this a bug in the sense that the behaviour of the Front End and the Kernel (run in command line mode) are consistent with each other.

Yes, this does make code like `"asd *)"` un-commentable, so you might call it bad design.   But I wouldn't call it a bug.

Contrast this with certain bugs where the Front End parses expressions differently from the Kernel.  For example, the M10.0.2 front end still has some difficulties with expressions of the type `#"one two"` while the kernel handles them.  The existence of these types of bugs proves that the Front End and Kernel do indeed use separate parsers.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because characters inside the comment are not actually parsed.  Ponder these two code fragments:

```
(*  "This string contains the end of a comment  *)"  *)
(*  "This comment begins with a quote character *)
```

How can the parser tell whether the quote is the start of a string or just a quote?

Answer (score 1):

the "bug":

```
(*"this is a bug*)"*)
```

the work around:

```
(*"this is a solution\*)"*)
```

Comment: If the closing `*)` is, like in Murta's case, part of a working *Mathematica* expression, I wouldn't use this because when you un-comment the region again, you have to go through your entire expression and remove the `\`. Using `(*(*` at the beginning is easier IMO here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the procedure outlined in the first Answer to [40396](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40396/behaviour-of-out-with-comments), the internal representation of

```
(*"this is a bug*)"*)
```

is

```
RowBox[{RowBox[{"(*", "\"\<this is a bug\>", "*)"}], "\"\<*)\>"}]
```

We see that `(*"this is a bug*)` is interpreted as a comment, and `"*)` as additional code that is syntactically incorrect.  As other Answers here have explained, this is not surprising.

If someone really wants to display this item, it can be accomplished with

```
RowBox[{RowBox[{"(*", "\"\<this is a bug\>", "*)"}], "\"\<*)\>"}]//DisplayForm
```

yielding

```
(*"this is a bug*)"*)
```

in an `In` cell (but without the red color, which is added by SE).